# wierd tables in mysql system database - mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I can see additional tables in the mysql system database in mariadbin our environment:

below is the output of show tables:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show full tables;
+---------------------------+------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           | Table_type |
+---------------------------+------------+
| ahelkk                    | BASE TABLE |
| ahxgcg                    | BASE TABLE |
| akysit32                  | BASE TABLE |
| amtyyy                    | BASE TABLE |
| aucykv32                  | BASE TABLE |
| avjyfr                    | BASE TABLE |
| azimlo32                  | BASE TABLE |
| bdbtrg32                  | BASE TABLE |
| bguwtk32                  | BASE TABLE |
| blpqss                    | BASE TABLE |
| brafih                    | BASE TABLE |
| bsbwxu                    | BASE TABLE |
| ccadhg32                  | BASE TABLE |
| cmdtsw32                  | BASE TABLE |
| column_stats              | BASE TABLE |
| columns_priv              | BASE TABLE |
| ctpsqi                    | BASE TABLE |
| ctrkwg                    | BASE TABLE |
| cyubjk                    | BASE TABLE |
| db                        | BASE TABLE |
| event                     | BASE TABLE |
| fbuiud                    | BASE TABLE |
| fjzzfq32                  | BASE TABLE |
| flrqbb32                  | BASE TABLE |
| fqewut32                  | BASE TABLE |
| fryhrd                    | BASE TABLE |
| func                      | BASE TABLE |
| gbsutw                    | BASE TABLE |
| general_log               | BASE TABLE |
| gmidqb                    | BASE TABLE |
| gothrx                    | BASE TABLE |
| gtid_slave_pos            | BASE TABLE |
| gzsvhs32                  | BASE TABLE |
| hdeavq32                  | BASE TABLE |
| help_category             | BASE TABLE |
| help_keyword              | BASE TABLE |
| help_relation             | BASE TABLE |
| help_topic                | BASE TABLE |
| host                      | BASE TABLE |
| hrkyld32                  | BASE TABLE |
| hygrpv32                  | BASE TABLE |
| ibugsz                    | BASE TABLE |
| ihpyuc                    | BASE TABLE |
| index_stats               | BASE TABLE |
| innodb_index_stats        | BASE TABLE |
| innodb_table_stats        | BASE TABLE |
| iozatq32                  | BASE TABLE |
| jnuujq                    | BASE TABLE |
| jqugjw                    | BASE TABLE |
| kbnvvb                    | BASE TABLE |
| kekqtj                    | BASE TABLE |
| kftigg32                  | BASE TABLE |
| laohij                    | BASE TABLE |
| mkgqnj32                  | BASE TABLE |
| mljiue32                  | BASE TABLE |
| molina                    | BASE TABLE |
| mwpefl32                  | BASE TABLE |
| nbbphu                    | BASE TABLE |
| ngyful                    | BASE TABLE |
| niggpy32                  | BASE TABLE |
| nljabx32                  | BASE TABLE |
| noncef32                  | BASE TABLE |
| nqndzp32                  | BASE TABLE |
| ochwks32                  | BASE TABLE |
| oifzmo                    | BASE TABLE |
| otrjmp32                  | BASE TABLE |
| ovpjpb                    | BASE TABLE |
| ozecir32                  | BASE TABLE |
| pgyniw32                  | BASE TABLE |
| plugin                    | BASE TABLE |
| proc                      | BASE TABLE |
| procs_priv                | BASE TABLE |
| proxies_priv              | BASE TABLE |
| ptetpt                    | BASE TABLE |
| pxpdnv                    | BASE TABLE |
| pywfzl                    | BASE TABLE |
| qdfngi32                  | BASE TABLE |
| qfbsjj                    | BASE TABLE |
| qjrzhs32                  | BASE TABLE |
| qxxtry                    | BASE TABLE |
| rmiuit                    | BASE TABLE |
| roles_mapping             | BASE TABLE |
| rpppwd32                  | BASE TABLE |
| rrmxoy32                  | BASE TABLE |
| servers                   | BASE TABLE |
| sgjqvv                    | BASE TABLE |
| slow_log                  | BASE TABLE |
| svmelw32                  | BASE TABLE |
| table_stats               | BASE TABLE |
| tables_priv               | BASE TABLE |
| tebato                    | BASE TABLE |
| tempMix                   | BASE TABLE |
| tempMix1                  | BASE TABLE |
| tempMix4                  | BASE TABLE |
| time_zone                 | BASE TABLE |
| time_zone_leap_second     | BASE TABLE |
| time_zone_name            | BASE TABLE |
| time_zone_transition      | BASE TABLE |
| time_zone_transition_type | BASE TABLE |
| ugtpei32                  | BASE TABLE |
| uktxny                    | BASE TABLE |
| user                      | BASE TABLE |
| utimtd                    | BASE TABLE |
| vshiuk32                  | BASE TABLE |
| wtuhjh                    | BASE TABLE |
| xgdwfu32                  | BASE TABLE |
| xgxdti32                  | BASE TABLE |
| xzsihp32                  | BASE TABLE |
| yopjcy32                  | BASE TABLE |
| zchwft                    | BASE TABLE |
| zefdjd                    | BASE TABLE |
| zmbics32                  | BASE TABLE |
+---------------------------+------------+
112 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please can anyone help me understand the wierd tables in the mysql system database other than the usual ones which are present.

Also these tables have columns of type longblob for example:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> describe zmbics32;
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| data  | longblob | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is this something a mariadb behaviour or an application behavious.

I have checked with the application team and they are convinced that it is not the application creating these tables.

Please shed some light.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Has your system been hacked into?  Do you have a weak 'root' password?  Do you have a web site that connects to MySQL?  Have you protected against 'sql injection'?

Answer (score 0):

All tables other than the usual system tables must have been created by either some application or user outside server. The following options (if enabled) can help you understand when/who/how these tables were created :

- [General query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/general-query-log/)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/information-schema-tables-table/)
- [Audit log plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-audit-plugin/)